# How to create github repo using powershell script

Tags: git, powershell, github, bitbucket

I am new to powershell scripting and git. I am working with a code that will help to transfer bitbucket repositories to github by running a powershell script. The script works well, but I am trying to modify it so it is able to create a github repository using the name from bitbucket, instead of manually having to create repos in github.

This is the portion I am trying to modify. As it is this code doesn't create a github repo but relies on an existing empty/new repo folder.

```
    # Clone bburl'
    Write-Output 'Cloning Bitbucket Repo...'
    git clone --mirror $bburl

    # Cd into newly created git folder
    Write-Output 'Opening Git Folder...'
    $reponame = ([System.Uri]$bburl).Segments[([System.Uri]$bburl).Segments.Count - 1]
    # set location
    cd $reponame
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Github API?

Comment: Yes, but it's only been used to access the pre-existing repo and transfer contents from the BB repo

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user

Comment: In fact, you *must* use the GitHub API; base Git doesn't have a "create repository" kind of operation other than on-the-local-machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitHub [CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli).

Use [gh repo create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) to create a repository.

Comment: I think this is what I need. Thanks! I'm going to read it in detail.